# Text get overlapped while scrolling in UI table view?

Tags: ios, swift

I had tried this method and I am using a label as a subview to the table cell the text in the label gets overlapped with the previous cell label content while scrolling

```
var tableCell: CommentTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentCell") as? CommentTableViewCell
        tableCell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
   if (tableCell == nil) {
            println("table view is working")
            tableCell = CommentTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"CommentCell")
}

}
```

[image: This is the result I got while scrolling]

Comment: What exactly is your problem ? Can you provide more description and/or screenshots to illustrate ?

Comment: The label content gets overlapped with the previous cell while scrolling through the table view

Comment: You need upvote to be able to upload screenshot

Comment: Okay this is the result I got while scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You have to set property for each cell in cellAtIndexPath. This kind of things mostly happen when you have images, but is reproducible with text as well.  Lets say that you have custom cell, then you will have to check every time if that particular row has label, text, image etc.

Why does this kind of behavior happen? Because each of your cells are reused, and if reused cell does contain text that you don't have in a "new" cell, or image, or whatever, that will remain and create you an inconsistent bug.

How do you resolve it?

Try to set empty text when you get the cell. If your cell is custom, set both your label to empty string and default cells title label to empty string. Then retrieve your comment from array and assign it. If you provide some more code I will post you what should be changed.(I need cellAtIndexPath method).

So this is your code:

```
var tableCell: CommentTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentCell") as? CommentTableViewCell
let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(60, 25, 255, 50)) 
label.attributedText = text1 label.numberOfLines = 0 
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping; 
let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13.0) 
label.font = font label.sizeToFit(); 
tableCell!.addSubview(label)
```

As I said in comment, your problem is adding label for each reused cell which will create overlapping. To fix this try:

```
var tableCell: CommentTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentCell") as? CommentTableViewCell
if(!tableCell)
{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(60, 25, 255, 50)) 
    label.attributedText = text1 label.numberOfLines = 0 
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping; 
    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13.0) 
    label.font = font label.sizeToFit(); 
    label.tag = 1; //This is tag added
    // add text
    tableCell!.addSubview(label) 
}
else
{
        let label : UILabel = (UILabel *)cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel?
        // add text
}
```

Comment: var tableCell: CommentTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CommentCell") as? CommentTableViewCell
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(60, 25, 255, 50))
        label.attributedText = text1
       label.numberOfLines = 0
       label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;
        let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13.0)
        label.font = font
        label.sizeToFit();
         tableCell!.addSubview(label)

Comment: This is what I had done to display the content in custom cell

Comment: I am not able to edit my post since there is some kind of suggestion, but your problem here is adding new label each time you reuse your cell. To fix this you can add tag, so when you reuse your cell you can reuse labels as well. Here is an example: if (cell == nil) { //your basic init you already got for label  label.tag = 1 } else { label =  self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel;} . I will post this formated asap :)

Comment: The If condition doesn't satisfy and it reporting a error hence I just changed it to         if(tableCell == nil) still the problem occurs

Comment: what error do you get?  you can do the same if you try to get the view and if that return nil, create UILabel with that tag.

Comment: Seems like you have sent me a meesage which I can't find... Can you post it here instead

Comment: I can't empty the table cell this is the issue and hence the condition is not satisfied

Comment: Yeah, that condition should be executed only if you have released cell for some reason, more important is else part where you get existing label and change the text... If your app crashes just post the error message

Comment: Yeah only the else part is satisfied the if condition is not satisfied and I am not getting any nil values while scrolling or  when the text get overlapped

Comment: Yeah, we agree on that, you should get else part satisfied. Do you get the label in else part ? have you assigned corresponding text in the else part ? and is it overlapping now ?

Comment: This is what I had done I just modified the if part alone as it shows a error to modify the condition and still the text get overlapped         
if(tableCell == nil)
        {
             let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(60, 25, 255, 50))
            label.attributedText = text1
           ...
             tableCell!.addSubview(label) 

        
        }
        
        
        else
        {
 
            let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(60, 25, 255, 50))
            label.attributedText = text1
..
                       tableCell!.addSubview(label) 

        }

Comment: You are adding label again. in the if part you assign tag and then reuse the label in the else statement. Just refer to the code I added. this part --> tableCell!.addSubview(label) <-- is causing overlap

Comment: It displays an error found nil while unwrapping an optional value
        let label : UILabel = tableCell!l.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
as this statement is returning nil value

Comment: okay, try this: if the UILabel is null, add it, if not reuse it. Don't forget to assign tag to the Label as you need it to get label from cell. Otherwise you will get overlaying labels again.

Comment: Thank you I had made it out by using a outlet in custom cell